# Facebook Like button shows ugly content of the post

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

I have just put Like button to my WordPress page below the post. I used Like Button Plugin but I tried also standard way of putting the code provided by FB developers page with same results. The information shared on Facebook after clicking the button doesn't look good. Just please compare the screenshots below.

Post on my blog

[image: post on my blog]

Like button output

[image: Like button output]

The like button includes meta data like author, date etc. and the site name 2x... and does not show the image ebeded into the post... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Debug the URL here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object

You will find out that you are missing some metadata. `og:image`, for example. There is only `og:title`.

Also, you should put the metatags before all those stylesheets.